# How to detect pan and zoom action in matplotlib navibar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I am using the matplotlib canvas and navbar by creating a custom MplWidget in python, as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as
        FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
        self.canvas.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas.toolbar)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.axes.grid(b=True, which='both', axis='both')
        self.canvas.figure.set_tight_layout(True)
```

I want to detect when the pan or the zoom tool is toggled. I found this: [in matplotlib how do I catch that event "zoom tool" has been selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842267/in-matplotlib-how-do-i-catch-that-event-zoom-tool-has-been-selected)
Following the solution there, I tried

```
self.canvas.toolbar.get_state()['_current_action']
```

or simply just `self.canvas.toolbar.get_state()`, but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigationToolbar2QT' object has no attribute 'get_state'
```

It seems like a very basic function to see which action is in use currently, so I am sure there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.

[zoom toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOBFA.png)

Comment: You may have to inspect the matplotlob files to figure this one out. I recall that the toolbars from the different backends do not all have the same methods. If you look at the toolbar source code you may find there are functions that are called when the toolbar buttons are toggled. If so, you can override them. I was able to do this in a much older mpl version for a similar purpose to you. I don't have access to that example any more to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two solutions, but I don't know if they work with all kinds of backends (not an expert in those).

---

The first is axes-dependant:

```
ax.get_navigate_mode()
```

it returns 'PAN', 'ZOOM', or None.

([Link to documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_navigate_mode.html))

---

The second is figure-dependant:

```
fig.canvas.toolbar.mode
```

it returns "pan/zoom", "zoom rect" or "".

([Link to source code of the NavigationToolbar2 object](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6a9a07155c0e7f91c20dd4c7e280198ec652c4ae/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2971))